# Object lookup using a HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I am trying to use a Java `HashMap<String, object>` as an object dictionary to lookup an object by its name (`string`).  All the names will be unique; but, often very similar (ex: "delay1", "delay2").  Does the `HashMap.get(string)` guarantee to find the unique item with that name or does is just look for one with the same hash?

The way the code is running, it looks like the lookup is not consistent.

If the `HashMap<String, object>` will not work for what I need, is there something in Java that will work similar to a C# Dictionary?

Comment: `HashMap` guarantees it will return the value for the key you're looking for. Can you share some code that shows how "the lookup is not consistent" please?

Comment: @markshancock `HashMap` behaves almost exactly like C#'s dictionary. The two biggest differences are (1) `HashMap` allows storing `null` key, and (2) `HashMap` returns `null` when the key is missing, instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: @Mureinik It looks like the problem is that the objects are disappearing from the HashMap.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33840064.  There is also more info on the class design there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `HashMap` guarantees to find the exact match, not just one with an identical hash code.

Hash-based containers do it by invoking `equals()` on the lookup key and the candidate from one of its hash buckets, to ensure that there is an actual match. That is the reason behind having to always override both `equals` and `hashCode` methods, as described in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()):

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the `hashCode` method whenever this [`equals`] method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the `hashCode` method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.